# AWS Glue Connection - test connection missing

Tags: aws-glue

I've created the Connection in AWS Glue and want to test it. The documentation says:

> Select the check box next to the desired connection, and then choose **Test connection**.
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/console-test-connections.html

For some reason I cannot find the `Test connection` option in the AWS Console. There is also no `Test connection` option in the connector page.

[image]

Where can I find it, or are there alternative ways to test the connection?

Answer (score 1):

In the new Glue console, there is no test connection option, but they have wrapped all the old pages under "legacy pages." Click [here](https://images.app.goo.gl/rYvi5zSA84o8iYzE8)!
in this below-left corner.